# Layout with CSS (or should I give up and use tables?)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the following Layout, as per screenshot.

[image: Layout using tables]

Main features are

- Screen divided into 3 regions (columns);
- Left / Right columns are fixed width;
- Middle column expands as per Browser width
- Right column is subdivided into two regions
- Bottom region is fixed size, always at the bottom
- Top region expands as per Browser height

Using HTML-tables took me about 2 hours to generate the above screenshot, with the above features.

After stuffing around with CSS for two days, I cannot get it looking as above, my attempt at CSS and associated screenshot follow below:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Layout</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css"> 
    body{
        height:100%;
        background:beige;
    }

    #header { 
        width:100%;
        height:60px;
        text-align:center;
        background:#A7C942; 
        color:#fff;
        float:left; 
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:2em;
    } 

    #leftDiv { 
        float:left; 
        width:150px;
        height:90%;
        background:aquamarine; 
    } 
    #midDiv { 
        float:left; 
        width:auto; 
        height:90%;
        background:lightsalmon; 
        display:block;
    } 
    #rightDiv { 
        float:right; 
        width:365px; 
        height:90%;
        background:green; 
        display:block;
    }


    #topRow {
        background-color:lightgoldenrodyellow;
    }

    #bottomRow {
        background-color:lightpink;
        height:200px;
    }
    </style> 
</head> 

<body> 
<div id="body"> 
    <div id="main"> 
        <div id="header">my header</div>

        <div id="leftDiv">
            <p>LEFT</p>
        </div> 

        <div id="midDiv">
            <p>MIDDLE</p>
        </div> 

        <div id="rightDiv">
            <p>RIGHT</p>
            <div id="topRow">
                TOP
            </div>
            <div id="bottomRow">
                BOTTOM
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Screenshot with CSS:
[image: Layout using CSS]

Problems with the CSS attempt are:

- Middle col does not expand (salmon colored part);
- instead white color appears out of nowhere;
- cannot get pink region to stay at the bottom always
- Cannot get yellow region to stretch up and down
- unwanted wrapping (i.e. the right region goes under left, middle regions)

Therefore, I am about to unleash my solution using tables, unless some die-hard CSS fanatic comes to the rescue with a working answer:-)

**Update**
Great answers, at the time of this update there were 4. I tried out all 4 on Firefox and Chrome, and every answer is acceptable. But i can only choose one as the accepted answer, and i will go with the one that's plain and simple using only css and absolute positioning (no flexbox nor css-tables).

Thank you muchly to @matthewelsom, @Pangloss, @Shrinivas, @Paulie_D; I am sure anyone who stumbles upon your answers will find it useful for their use case. Upvotes for everyone, your efforts are appreciated!

Comment: Why dont you  use bootstrap? It will make this simplier and responsive http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: @DavidChavez Definitely the right choice here.

Comment: Really well laid out question. Don't use bootstrap, learn to do it 'properly'!

Comment: @DavidChavez why not indeed, I didn't think of that. But the question is can it be done? or will i be spending another two days two find out it can't be done.

Comment: I don't think BS is the best approach, you will still need to fix all of the fixed width issues... certainly the expanding middle section will be difficult with Bootstrap. I think you are better off using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Consider using flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: To the flexbox fans, how big is flexbox library? is it comparable to jquery in size?

Comment: flexbox is native CSS, so nothing extra!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/70qu6fk6/2/).

It uses basic **CSS** and **HTML** and **NO framework**.

The key elements which allows this type of positioning are these css properties:
`left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`.

The demo uses these properties.

Here is the snippet.

```css
body {
  background: beige;
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #A7C942;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
}
#leftDiv {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: aquamarine;
}
#midDiv {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 150px;
  right: 365px;
  min-width: 50px;
  background: lightsalmon;
}
#rightDiv {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  width: 365px;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: green;
}
#topRow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
#bottomRow {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightpink;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="main">
    <div id="header">my header</div>
    <div id="leftDiv">
      <p>LEFT</p>
    </div>
    <div id="midDiv">
      <p>MIDDLE</p>
    </div>
    <div id="rightDiv">
      <div id="topRow">TOP</div>
      <div id="bottomRow">BOTTOM</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Hanoncs Shrinivas Shukla didn't use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or similar to get the OP's desired results.

Comment: I noticed few people suggesting Bootstrap in the comments section and I didn't use that or anything similar. Just clarified that.

Comment: Oh ok, I was wondering, I thought you that thought flexbox was a framework.

Answer (score 3):

Here we go the CSS table layout, adjusted the markup slightly - added a couple of `<div>` containers for applying the styles.

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wzj1gjm7/)**

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#page, #main, #rTable {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width :100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#page > div {
    display: table-row;
}
#page #hRow {
    background: lightgreen;
    text-align: center;
}
#page #mRow {
    height: 100%;
}
#main > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#leftDiv {
    width: 100px;
    background: aquamarine;
}
#midDiv {
    background: lightsalmon;
}
#rightDiv {
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
}
#rTable > div {
    display: table-row;
}
#rTable #topRow {
    background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
#rTable #bottomRow {
    height: 100px;
    background: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
    <div id="hRow">
        <div id="header">HEADER</div>
    </div>
    <div id="mRow">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="leftDiv">
                <p>LEFT</p>
            </div>
            <div id="midDiv">
                <p>MIDDLE</p>
            </div>
            <div id="rightDiv">
                <div id="rTable">
                    <div id="topRow">RIGHT-TOP</div>
                    <div id="bottomRow">RIGHT-BOTTOM</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick flex layout, very rough but you'll get the idea. 
You can read more about Flexbox on [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

I have also made the design responsive so the layout will fill 100% width on screens under 480px width.

[CODEPEN HERE](http://codepen.io/matthewelsom/pen/VLQmdE)

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
  display: -webkit-box;  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
  display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
  
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper > * {
   flex: 1 100%;
  -webkit-flex: 1 100%; 
}

.header {
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1; 
  
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 80px;
}

.below {
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1; 
  
  display: flex;        
  display: -webkit-box;  
  display: -ms-flexbox; 
  display: -webkit-flex;  
  
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.main {
  background: deepskyblue;
  flex: 3 0px;
  -webkit-flex: 3 0px;
  
  -webkit-order: 2;
  order: 2;
}

.left {
  background: yellow;
  max-width: 100px;
  flex: 1 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
  
  -webkit-order: 1;
  order: 1;
}

.right {
  background: hotpink;
  max-width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  
  display: flex;        
  display: -webkit-box;  
  display: -ms-flexbox; 
  display: -webkit-flex;  
  
  flex: 1 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
  
  -webkit-order: 3;
  order: 3;
  
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.top {
  background: lightpink;
  
  flex: 1 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
}
.bottom {
  background: salmon;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  
  flex: 1 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .below {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .left, .right, .main {
    max-width: 100%;
    
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
  }
  body, html, .wrapper {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header"><h3>Header</h3><p>Fixed height 80px, 100% width</p></header>
  <div class="below">
    <article class="main">
    <h3>Flexible width Article</h3>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </article>
    <aside class="left">
      <h3>Left</h3>
      <p>100px fixed width</p>
    </aside>
    <aside class="right">
    <div class="top">
      <h3>Right Top</h3>
      <p>Flexible Height, Fixed width 300px</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <h3>Right Bottom</h3>
      <p>Fixed width 300px, Fixed Height 200px</p>
    </div>
  </aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to see more flexbox.  Just wish we didn't have that [pesky IE nonsense](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) to deal with.

Comment: Note the following: TOP + BOTTOM = ASIDE = MAIN. BOTTOM = height:200px;

Comment: Great job, but proper responsible web development would use all the versions of flexbox prefixes. Any android before 4.4 will break without prefixes, IE 10 will break without prefixes...Please add them to your answer!

Comment: i would say either spend a lot of time looking at the browser specific versions of flexbox, because that csstricks article does not include all prefixes for flexbox. Or you can just use this which is awesome! http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/

Comment: @Hanoncs, thanks for that, I shall take a look. I usually use SCSS with  [bourbon](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/css3/_flex-box.scss) to take the heavy lifting away.

Comment: Bonus for stacking sections vertically on small screens.

Answer (score 2):

Using flexbox this is actually pretty simple.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/YXepbg)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  width: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  flex: none;
}
.center {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: salmon;
}
.right {
  width: 300px;
  flex:none;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.top {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: 000;
}
.bottom {
  height: 50px;
  flex: none;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h2>Header</h2>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="col left">Fixed Left</div>
    <div class="col center">Flexible Center</div>
    <div class="col right">
      <div class="top">Top Flexible Height inside fixed Right</div>
      <div class="bottom">fixed Height Bottom</div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

[**CSS-Tricks.com Ultimate Guide**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Prefixes will be required.

Support Reference: [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: Great job, but proper responsible web development would use all the versions of flexbox prefixes. Any android before 4.4 will break without prefixes, IE 10 will break without prefixes...Please add them to your answer!

Comment: How about I just edit your answer? Surely the community will accept it since the current answer is lazy and just trying to get cred.

Comment: I already have enough "cred"  thanks....I've answered enough of these to know what and isn't required. Gilding the lily really isn't required.

Comment: Besides that, an answer doesn't have to be a 100% production ready answer.